# I m using Post Method but Apache keep saying GET not supported, Why?

Tags: ajax, rest, spring-boot, web, httprequest

I m making a small web/application to exercise what I m learning from Spring boot and ajax.

I have a web page where I have a form that have two date inputs 'start date' and 'end date' I wanted to send the user input to a RestController and to get a response that I should show in a empty div

here is what I have done till now

My Form :

```
        <div class="w3-container w3-padding-64" id="reserver_salle">
            <h1>Resrvation de salle</h1><br>
            <form id="reserver_salle_form" >
                <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16" id="dateDebut" type="date" required placeholder="Date début"></p>
                <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16" id="dateFin" type="date" required placeholder="Date fin"></p>
                <p><button id="searchSalle" type="submit" class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-section" >[[#{homePage.envoyer}]]</button></p>
            </form>
        </div>


        <div id="salleList" class="w3-container">

        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{~/cdnjs.cloudflare.com_ajax_libs_jquery_2.1.3_jquery.min.js}">
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{~/js/start_page.js}"></script>
```

Now I will show you my ajax script

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //alert("is loading");

        $("#searchSalle").submit(function (event) {

            //stop submit the form, we will post it manually.
            event.preventDefault();

            fire_serach_salle();

        });

        $("#send_mail").submit(function (event) {

            //stop submit the form, we will post it manually.
            event.preventDefault();

            fire_send_mail();

        });

    });


    function fire_serach_salle(){


        var searchReserv = {};

        searchReserv["dateDebutAnnee"]  = $("#dateDebut").val().split('-')[0];
        searchReserv["dateDebutMois"]  = $("#dateDebut").val().split('-')[1];
        searchReserv["dateDebutJour"] = $("#dateDebut").val().split('-')[2];
        searchReserv["dateFinAnnee"]    = $("#dateFin").val().split('-')[0];
        searchReserv["dateFinMois"]    = $("#dateFin").val().split('-')[1];
        searchReserv["dateFinJour"]   = $("#dateFin").val().split('-')[2];

        $("#searchSalle").prop("disabled",true);

        console.log(searchReserv);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "/homePage/reservation/search",
            data: JSON.stringify(searchReserv),
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 900000,

            success: function (result) {
                if (result.answer === "DONE") {

                /*<![CDATA[*/
                    var html ='<h2>Liste des salles </h2>';
                        html+='<ul  class="w3-ul w3-hoverable">';
                    for(var i = 0 ;i<result.data.length;i++){
                        html += ' <li class="w3-display-container ">'+result.data[i].titre+'-'+result.data[i].id+'<span onclick="reserve('+result.data[i].id+')" class="w3-button w3-transparent w3-display-right w3-hover-green">reserver</span></li>';
                    }
                        html+='</ul>';
                /*]]>*/
                    $("#salleList").html(html);

                    $("#searchSalle").prop("disabled",false);

                }
            }
        });



    }
```

now I will show my controller

```
    @RestController
    @PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "classpath:messages.properties")
    public class HomePageController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/homePage/reservation/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody
        AjaxResponse doSearch(@RequestBody SearchReserv searchReserv, Model model) {

            try {

                System.out.println(searchReserv);
                ArrayList<ReservationSearchResponse> response = new ArrayList<>();

                response.add(new ReservationSearchResponse(Long.valueOf(0), "hello 0"));
                response.add(new ReservationSearchResponse(Long.valueOf(1), "hello 1"));

                return new AjaxResponse("DONE", response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return new AjaxResponse("BAD", null);
            }

        }
```

Finally my two classes AjaxResponse and SearcheReserv

```
public class AjaxResponse {

  private String answer;
  private Object data;

  //geters setters and contructors
}

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 *
 * @author taleb
 */
@Component
public class SearchReserv {
  private int dateDebutAnnee;
  private int dateDebutMois;
  private int dateDebutJour;
  private int dateFinAnnee;
  private int dateFinMois;
  private int dateFinJour;
//geters setters and contructors
}
```

What I can't understand that I m using this way to implement a send mail using spring mail and it working fine

but in this one I still getting

> There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
>   Request method 'GET' not supported

there is no GET in my code

I m using latest Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7 
I have no configuration handmade on the apache server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of hard the issue was stupid, When attaching Ajax request we do it to the form Id not the Button

I fixed this by updating my ajax script from

```
$("#searchSalle").submit(function (event)
```

to

```
$("#reserver_salle_form").submit(function (event)
```

and it is working like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Try using annotation **@RequestMapping(method=GET)** and share the result after that. It should resolve this issue.